# Is there a harmonic function in the whole plane that is positive everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is one of the past qualifying exam problems that I was working on.

I know that, when we let $z=x+iy$, ${|z|}^2=x^2+y^2$ is not harmonic. I do not know where to start to prove that there is no harmonic function that is positive everywhere.

Any help or ideas idea will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Constant functions are harmonic...  An harmonic function in two variables is the real part of an entire holomorphic function.  So try to construct some *bounded* entire function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be entire with real part everywhere positive. Consider

$$h(z) = e^{-f(z)}$$

If $\Re f(z) > 0$, we have $-\Re f(z) < 0$, so $h(z)$ is bounded and entire. What can you conclude about $h(z)$, and hence about $f(z)$?

---

To go into a little more detail, note that

$$|h(z)| = e^{-\Re f(z)} < e^{0} < 1$$

Comment: this is elementary!

Comment: You mean if $u(x,y)>0$?

Comment: Even if we rewrite $f$ as $f(x+iy)=u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ and $u>0$, $h(z)=e^{-u(z)}e^{-iv(z)}=e^{-u(z)}(\cos(v(z))-i\sin(v(z)))$ and $Re(h(z))=e^{-u(z)}(\cos(v(z))$ can be negative depending on $v(z)$. Is it right? Would you give me more explanation?

Comment: @ Isaac Solomon: Thank you for the additional note, so since $h(z)$ is a bounded entire function, it is a constant function by Liouville's Theorem and so we conclude that the only harmonic function that is positive everywhere is a constant function. Is it correct?

Comment: Right, $h(z)$ is constant, and hence $f(z)$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing,a non-constant harmonic function is the real part of a non-constant entire function.so the real part must be positive.Little Picard Theorem: If a function  is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that f(z) assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point. so we get a contradiction

Comment: Do you mean that since $f(z)$ assumes the whole complex plane, $Re(f)$ which is harmonic should be negative for some z?

Comment: yes,Re(f) which is harmonic must also assume negative values

Answer (score 0):

### MORE GENERAL AND SIMPLE ANSWER

> Liouville Type (Theorem's)
>   Suppose $u:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ be a nonegaitve harmonic function 
>   Then, $u$ is constant.

**Proof**
$u\ge 0$ then $\inf_{\mathbb R^d} u<\infty$. Hence we set 
$$v= u-\inf_{\mathbb R^d} u$$
and

\begin{split} \begin{cases}\Delta v=0\\
v\ge 0\\
\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v =0\end{cases}\end{split}

Let $\varepsilon>0,$ and $y\in\mathbb R^d$  then there exists $x_\varepsilon$ such that,

$$ v(x_\varepsilon)\le \inf_{\mathbb R^d} v+\varepsilon$$

Let $R>\max(|x_\varepsilon|,|y|)+1$ therefore, $x_\varepsilon,y\in B_R(0)$ and

$$ B_R(y)\subset B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon) $$

**By Mean value property (The mean value is true in any dimension for harmonics functions)**,

\begin{split} v(y) &=& \frac{1}{|B_R(y)|}\int_{B_R(y)} v(z) dz\\ &=& \frac{3^d}{|B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)|}\int_{B_R(y)} v(z) dz \\&\le&\frac{3^d}{|B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)|}\int_{B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)} v(z) dz \\&= & 3^d v(x_\varepsilon) \end{split}
This leads to,

$$  v(y)\le 3^d v(x_\varepsilon)\le 3^d(\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v+\varepsilon)~~\forall y\in  \mathbb R^d$$

That is 
$$  \sup_{\mathbb R^d} v < 
  3^d \varepsilon $$

Since $\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v=0$ ~~ but $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrarily chosen, letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we get

$$ 0\le \sup_{\mathbb R^d} v  \le 0$$

i.e $v = 0$ or $u= \inf_{\mathbb R^d} u $