# Showing that if $u$ is a real-valued harmonic function then for any real $c$ we have that $u^{-1}(c)$ is unbounded

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have the following homework question:

> Let $u$ be a non-constant real-valued harmonic function in
>   $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $u^{-1}(c)$ is unbounded for every real
>   number $c$

There is a hint that say we may use the result of the following exercise:

> Prove that a positive harmonic function in $\mathbb{C}$ is
>   non-constant

This exercise is taken from

> Donald Sarason Notes on Complex Function Theory (page 89)

**What I tried:**

I don't really know how to start, but a reasonable beginning can be:

Assume by negation that there is $c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $$u^{-1}(c)\subseteq D(0,M)$$
where $$D(0,M)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\,|z|<M\}$$

We know that there is a harmonic conjugate $v$ s.t $$f=u+iv\in H(D(0,M))$$

I don't know how to move forward, or how to use the hint (since in
this question $u$ need not be a positive function).

Can someone please direct me in the right direction ?

Comment: Translate to get the case where $u^{-1}(0)$ is bounded.  Show that $u$ has a fixed sign outside a certain radius.  In case that sign is $+$, add a constant to get a positive harmonic function.

Comment: I don't understand the exercise you say is a hint. Why isn't the function $u(z)=1$ a counterexample?

Comment: It's difficult to know what you know. Do you know Green's formulas and their consequences for harmonic functions? Do you know that if you had a compact level set, you could apply the maximum/minimum principle?

Comment: @TedShifrin - that was a typo, sorry. I corrected it to mean constant instead of non-constant. I don't think I know "Green's formulas and their consequences for harmonic functions" but I do know the other things you mentioned

Comment: @GEdgar - thanks for the hint!

Comment: I have been studying on my exam and saw this question but can somebody be more clear how can we solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a positive harmonic function is *constant*. See [Does there exist a harmonic function in the whold plane that is postive everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267518/does-there-exist-a-harmonic-function-in-the-whold-plane-that-is-postive-everywhe)

Also, you should be able to use the fact that $u^{-1}(c)$ is bounded to conclude that, by continuity, everything falls on one side of $c$. This can be manipulated into giving you a positive harmonic function.