# If $u$ is harmonic then $u^{-1}(a)$ is unbounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ be a non constant real-valued harmonic function in $\mathbb{C}$ Prove that the set   $u^{-1}(c)$ is unbounded for every real number $\mathbb{C}$.

This  problem is there in the book "Complex Function Theory, Sarason". I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405793/showing-that-if-u-is-a-real-valued-harmonic-function-then-for-any-real-c-we)

The whole proof I got. but the only thing I didn't understood is 
:  **Due to continuity of $u$ and connectedness either $u(z)\ge c$ or $u(z)\le c$.**

Comment: I cannot find the phrase "Due to ..." in the link. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u^{-1}(c)$ is bounded then $u(z) \ne c$ outside of some disk with 
radius $R$. Then
$$
 \{ z : |z| > R \} = \{ z : |z| > R, u(z)<c \} \cup  \{ z : |z| > R, u(z)>c \} 
$$
is a decomposition of a connected set into two disjoint open sets,
so one of the sets on the right-hand side must be *empty.* 
(This is essentially a repetition of the argument that a continuous
function maps connected sets to connected sets.)

W.l.o.g assume that $u(z)>c$ for $|z| > R$, otherwise replace $u$ by $\tilde u = 2c - u$.

Also $u$ is bounded below on the compact set $|z| \le R$, and therefore
bounded below on all of $\Bbb C$, i.e. $u + M$ is a *positive*
harmonic function for some constant $M$.

Then continue as in [Does there exist a harmonic function in the whold plane that is postive everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267518/does-there-exist-a-harmonic-function-in-the-whold-plane-that-is-postive-everywhe).